# How to detect if an email address change was reverted?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was working on the user profile page of my app and I am allowing the user to change their email address. If the user email address is changed successfully, the data in the firebase database of the particular user will be updated. Also, After successfully changing the email address, firebase will send an email to the user's previous email address (the user email address before it was changed to the new one) asking if it was the actual owner of the account who changed the email address and there will be a link to reset their email. If the user chooses to reset the email (for whatever reason), the user's new email will be changed to the previous email. But the problem is that the data in the database will not be updated, how can I detect this change (email reset) and update the database?

```
authenticateUserAlert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Done", style: .default, handler: { [weak authenticateUserAlert] (_) in
    // Print the user email
    let emailTextField = authenticateUserAlert?.textFields![0]
    print("Email: \(emailTextField!.text!)")
    // Print the user password
    let passwordTextField = authenticateUserAlert?.textFields![1]
    print("Password: \(passwordTextField!.text!)")

    // Re-authenticate the user
    let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: emailTextField!.text!, password: passwordTextField!.text!)

    user?.reauthenticate(with: credential, completion: { (result, error) in
        if error != nil {

            // Alert: What ever the error
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
            Alerts.errorAlert(on: vc, error: error!.localizedDescription, dismissAlert: false)

        } else {
            print(result!)
            let editProfilePage = EditUserProfile()
            editProfilePage.updateUserInfo()
        }
    })
}))
```

**Here is what I tried according to an answer**

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload(completion: { (Error) in
    //Completion handler
    if let email = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email {
        UserDataRetrieval.userEmail = email
        self.emailLabel.text = email
        print(Auth.auth().currentUser?.email)
    }
})
```

[image: The email that will be sent to the user from firebase]
[image: Firebase datbase]

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of authentication you are using but honestly you should just use the email that is part of the authenticated account and then you don't need to worry about updating it in the database.

You can always just get the users email by using `Auth.auth().currentUser.email`

**Update**

Found a workaround to the issue of the credential data, try using

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.reload(completion: { (Error) in
    if (Error != nil) {
        //Do something with error
    } else {
        //Do something with success or do nothing
    }
})
```

Just call update credentials at the start of the app if you want to always have to most up to date credentials

Comment: Hey you sure this works? I reverted the email after changing but it still keeps returning the email address that I changed to

Comment: in the console when you click on the link is the email for the user reverted back? also what authentication method are you using?

Comment: let credential = EmailAuthProvider.credential(withEmail: emailTextField!.text!, password: passwordTextField!.text!)

Comment: The email in the authentication of the firebase page changes, but it doesn't return the email that I reverted to when I print the current user's email

Comment: Does it print the email when you close the app and open it again?

Comment: It prints the new email, not the one I reverted to (previous email)

Comment: Hey, no luck yet?

Comment: Testing it on a side project so give me a minute

Comment: it seems that the user email data is cached and is not immediately updated by firebase, try going through the process and then waiting an hour or a few hours and then restart the app and check to see if the email is the same or if it has been updated.

Comment: But the email in the authentication page of firebase is updated

Comment: I'm getting this error:- Invalid user token detected, user is automatically signed out.

Comment: I tried out your updated version, Is that code correct?

Comment: Lets continue this in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197261/discussion-between-smallworld-and-f22lightning).

Answer (score 0):

You can always build your own custom handler for the email change revocation landing page. In that landing page you can update your database.
Check the [official docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/custom-email-handler) on how to do that.